# Can someone please explain use of each_with_index, reduce, select chained in the code along with OR (||)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone explain this code to me? What does the `||` syntax mean and how does it work?

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9]

array.each_with_index.reduce({}) { |hash, (item, index)|
  hash[item] = (hash[item] || []) << index
  hash
}.select{ |key, value| value.size > 1 }
```

Comment: It's not pipeline, it's logical OR, it works similarily to most other programming languages.

Comment: Can you explain this code how the values in hash are getting stored

Comment: @VijaySharma: it may help understanding if you "uncompress" that line into 3-4 lines (by extracting variables). But first, read up on that logical OR and how it works in ruby (truthy/falsey values)

Answer (score 2):

I'd rewrite it this way

```
array.each_with_index.reduce(Hash.new { Array.new }) do |hash, (item, index)|
  hash.merge(item => hash[item] << index)
end.select { |_, indexes| indexes.size > 1 }
```

- We use [`each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) because we want to access the index while looping the array. You can see it later next to item as a parameter in the `reduce`'s block.
- [`reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) permits us to "transform" a collection in something else. In our case we want to construct an hash out of an array.
- In the `reduce`'s block we add the current index to the key value pair for the current item. I used [`merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) to do it in just one expression (update the hash and using it as an expression to return).
- In the end, we keep just the key value pairs whose values (and those are arrays) have more than one elements. Note that we don't care about keys here so I called the key parameter `_`.

Comment: `Hash.new { Array.new }` - careful with that, though, it's a trap :)

Comment: What do you mean? I would have said that to `Hash.new(Array.new)` :)

Comment: That too, but this one is worse. :) Doesn't persist _anything_ without an explicit `[]=`. https://eval.in/1093640

Comment: no-no, here it works out fine, because of `Hash#merge`. But one must keep an eye out, is all I'm saying :)

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9]

array.each_with_index.reduce({}) do |hash, (item, index)|
  hash[item] = (hash[item] || []) << index
  hash
end.select do |key, value|
  value.size > 1
end
```

First of all cleaner way of writing Enumerators single line are enclosed with `{}` and multiline with `do; end`.

```
array.each_with_index.reduce({}) do |hash, (item, index)|
  # hash[item] gets either itself and if itself is nil it gets an empty 
  # array assigned and additionally the index gets added to this array 
  hash[item] = (hash[item] || []) << index
  # return the hash for the reduce enumerator
  hash
end
```

In this part you iterate over the array and pass in the initial empty hash with `.reduce({})`. The hash then gets transformed and returned in L3 in the "loop" and passed into the next iteration of the `reduce`. Your result then is the build up `hash` which then immediately get enumerated with `select` where only key value pairs get returned that have a value size larger than 1.

Best would be to readup on [Enumerators#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#inject-method) and how the objects are passed into the "loop".

Comment: "and additionally the index gets added to this array" - and this array is saved back to the hash. I think being extra verbose would not hurt in this case :)

Answer (score -1):

`hash[item]` is `nil` at first. `nil || [] => []`, so `hash[item]` become array. `<<` push an item into array.

hope this can help you understand how hash store the value

```rb
require "pp"
hash = {}
pp hash[1] # => nil 
pp hash[1] || [] # => []
pp (hash[1] || []) << 1 # => [1]
pp hash[1] # => nil
hash[1] = (hash[1] || []) << 1
pp hash[1] # => [1]
```